# How to solve nonlinear equations in R

Tags: r, equation

For example, I try to solve for x: 12*exp(-2x/4)=0.5, or x^2+3x^4+9x^5=10, is there any method in R to solve such equations?

Comment: I don't think there is an algebra system in R. You should get reasonably good approximations with optimization through `optim` and `optimize`  though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `uniroot` function

```r
r1 <- uniroot(function(x) 12*exp(-x/2) - 0.5, c(-1000, 1000)) 
r2 <- uniroot(function(x) x^2 + 3*x^4 + 9*x^5 - 10, c(-1000, 1000))

r1$root
[1] 6.356108

r2$root
[1] 0.943561
```

You have to define:

1. a function of the type `f(x) = 0` (and remove the second member of equality)
2. an interval within which to search for the solution